# iOS Firestore 'Document path cannot be empty'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Document path cannot be empty.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Some people would get a similar issue because in an older version of Firebase, the check statements for document would only check for a nil string rather than an empty. The latests versions of Firebase check for nil and an empty string.

Comment: Generally not quite the right format for Stack Overflow, but if you think this is broadly useful to people, the better way to format this is as a question, and then post your own answer. There's time delay, but you can then mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @brandonscript your completely right, I will edit the post and include the answer, Ill just have to remember to mark it right in 2 days.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason why my app would crash:

I would initiate a sign in/ sign up view if the user is not signed in, if they are signed in then the app initiates a homeview, pretty common stuff. The issue was that I had created an instance of currentUser?.Uid as the document path, which would return empty if the user is not signed in, no user signed in means no UID which means no document path.

My firestore would go Users -> UID -> User.

Conclusion

If you have this issue make sure you are not creating an instance of currentUser?.UID for a document path anywhere in your app unless the user is signed in.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and my app would crash.

My code was:

```
func doesUserExist(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    guard AuthService.shared.Auth.auth().currentUser != nil else { return }
    firestore.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "").getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if snapshot != nil && error == nil {
            completion(snapshot!.exists)
        } else { completion(false) }
    }
}
```

^This would return empty document path.
So I changed my code to the following and it solved it:

```
func currentUserDoc() -> DocumentReference? {
    if AuthService.shared.Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        return firestore.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser?.uid ?? "")
    }
    return nil
}

func doesUserExist(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    guard AuthService.shared.Auth.auth().currentUser != nil else { return }
    currentUserDoc()?.getDocument { snapshot, error in
        if snapshot != nil && error == nil {
            completion(snapshot!.exists)
        } else { completion(false) }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: Hi, Gal. I got the same issues. But I don't know about only your codes. So please explain more. What is the difference from those?
And please show us how to call  and use the functions. Thank you.

Comment: Basically if the currentUserDoc is nil then it won't proceed to get the document if it's empty and then the app doesn't crash. When you check if the user is logged in but no document was written yet and you still  try to read it, it returns nil and that causes a crash.