# Firestore 'Document path cannot be empty.'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, in general, there is not much information regarding this error, and those that are do not solve the problem.
When registering \ logging in via `Apple Sign In`, a collection of `users` is created, for some reason the `name` is not displayed after logging in to your personal space, but this is not even the problem (I hope), there is a function to change the `name` in the settings, but after confirming the app crashes with error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Document path cannot be empty.'

From this thread:
[iOS Firestore 'Document path cannot be empty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608266/ios-firestore-document-path-cannot-be-empty)

I understood this:

> Some people would get a similar issue because in an older version of Firebase, the check statements for document would only check for a nil string rather than an empty. The latests versions of Firebase check for nil and an empty string.

But no matter what Im do I still get this error.

```
    static func updateUserName(with newName: String, uid: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {
        let reference = Firestore.firestore().collection(FBKeys.CollectionPath.users)
            .document(uid)
        reference.setData(["name": newName], merge: true) { err in
            if let err = err {
                completion(.failure(err))
                return
            }
            completion(.success(true))
        }
    }
```

So, in general, the question is clear, what exactly needs to be done with `.document(uid)`?

Comment: It sounds like your `uid` variable doesn't have a value or has a `""` value. You'll need to ensure that `uid` has a value before passing it to the Firestore `document` API call.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added inside update func: `let user = Auth.auth().currentUser` and changed `document(uid)` to `document(user?.uid ? "")` and the `name` started to show in app after updating also the `name` changed inside the `users` collection, but as soon as I close the app, the `name` ceases to be displayed, and if I log in again to the same account, then the `name` in the collection changes to an empty string, strange things.